# Почему scanf записывает только в последнюю из перечисленных переменных?

Tags: c++

В чем ошибка? Почему я получаю ответ `h: 0, m: 0, s: 54` ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    short int h, m, s;
    char line[] = "10 45 54";

    sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &h, &m, &s);
    cout << "h: " << h << ", m: " << m << ", s: " << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` - для `int`, или исправьте на `%hd`, или используйте переменные типа `int`.

Кстати, VC++ честно предупреждает при компиляции:

```
test.cpp(10): warning C4477: "sscanf": в строке форматирования "%d" требуется аргумент типа "int *", но вариативный аргумент "1" имеет тип "short *"
test.cpp(10): note: рекомендуется использовать "%hd" в строке форматирования
test.cpp(10): warning C4477: "sscanf": в строке форматирования "%d" требуется аргумент типа "int *", но вариативный аргумент "2" имеет тип "short *"
test.cpp(10): note: рекомендуется использовать "%hd" в строке форматирования
test.cpp(10): warning C4477: "sscanf": в строке форматирования "%d" требуется аргумент типа "int *", но вариативный аргумент "3" имеет тип "short *"
test.cpp(10): note: рекомендуется использовать "%hd" в строке форматирования
```

Comment: Вот спасибо, я бы наверно еще часа 3 пробовал всё подряд.

Comment: Вообще-то не стоит явно использовать типы `int` `short` и прочие, следует использовать стандартные типы фиксированный длины из `<cstdint>`, `::std::int32_t` в данном случае.

Comment: @VTT я начинающий в С++. Спасибо за информацию, но я еще не скоро приду к этому. К тому же не думаю, что это так важно для решение задач на acmp.ru :)

Comment: @ИванАнтонов Еще для использования `scanf` следует включать заголовочный файл `<cstdio>`.

Comment: @VTT зачем же, он есть в iostream. В ином случае я бы получил ошибку при компиляции `[Error] 'scanf' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @ИванАнтонов По стандарту `scanf` объявляется в заголовочном файле `<cstdio>`. То, что в данном примере не происходит ошибки компиляции - просто случайность, видимо `cstdio` так или иначе уже включен в `iostream`. В других реализациях стандартной библиотеки это может и не прокатить.